# finding maximum distance of twice occuring numbers in Array

Tags: algorithm

currently I am solving old exams and had a problem with this one:
Given a field A containing an even number n of integers. Each number in A
occurs exactly twice. Thus, there are n/2 different numbers in A.
I am looking for an algorithm that determines the largest distance dmax between two identical numbers
in A have from each other. So firstly in O(n*dmax) Secondly in O(nlogn)

Thanks!

Hashmap and saving each first occurance of a number then updating dmax while iterating through A, however I don't think this is the answer that the professor was looking for.

Comment: I like your approach, and it will be generally better than O(nlogn).... but if the prof is looking for O(nlogn) then maybe look into something with a sort in there. Perhaps construct a list of (value,index) pairs, sort them, then the duplicates will be adjacent for easy scanning ...

Comment: _however I don't think this is the answer that the professor was looking for_. Well, we can't guess what he expects. Do you have a more concrete question?

Comment: Your solution is O(n), which is also in O(n log n) and O(n*dmax). What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna be guessing, obviously ;)

First O(n*dmax):

The most naive approach fits. For each number, we search backward and forward simultaneously going one step further / back in each iteration. What is the complexity? Not more than n * 2 * dmax. There is an possibility, that all distances are equal, so worst case scenario (expressed with dmax - not sure if it's the worst case scenario when we use only `n`) is O(n*dmax) - consider an array:

```
[n1, n2, ..., nk, n1, n2, ..., nk]
```

Second O(n*logn):

That's what you get if, instead of hashmap, you would use treemap. Not sure if that's the idea behind it, though.

Edit:

I thought of different n*logn approach:
Sort an array of structs - unique value of a numbers from array and two indices where those values are. Sorting takes n*logn. Then go through the original array and save indices of each number in the array of structs. It takes again n times finding proper struct - binary search = logn. Then find max of differences in the array of structs. This algorithm doesn't require any external structure.

Comment: Yes the O(n*dmax) solutions sounds exactly right!

Comment: I have an Idea for the O(nlogn) Solution: It would be a divide and Conquer algorithm in which we recursively find the max distance in left and right part of the array and then combine the two. Similar to a closest pair of points problem

Answer (score 0):

share my opinions, hopeful not  misunderstand the question :)

This algorithm has a time complexity of `O(n)` :

- Create a dictionary `dict` to store the indices of each number in the field `A`.
- Initialize `dmax` to be `0`.
- Iterate through each number `num` in the field `A`.
- If `num` is not in `dict`, add it to dict with its index as the value.
- Otherwise, calculate the distance `d` between the current index and the index stored in `dict` for `num`.
- If `d` is greater than `dmax`, update `dmax` to `d`.
- Return `dmax`.

Here's how to modify this algorithm to have a time complexity of O(nlogn):

1. Sort the field `A`.
2. Initialize `dmax` to be 0.
3. Iterate through each number `num` in the sorted field `A`.
4. Use binary search to find the index of the first occurrence of `num` in the sorted field `A`.
5. Use binary search to find the index of the last occurrence of `num` in the sorted field `A`.
6. Calculate the distance `d` between the first and last occurrence of `num`.
7. If `d` is greater than `dmax`, update `dmax` to `d`.
8. Return `dmax`.

The time complexity of this algorithm is O(nlogn) due to the sorting and the use of binary search.